# resolve a subdomain in debian 10

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a server with active directory and dns on windows server 2012 with the following subdomain:

ac: alm.local <--- 10.0.0.3

dns hosts:

javi.a.alm.local <---- 10.0.0.20

when I solve in windows:

```
nslookup javi.a

server: localhost
address: 127.0.0.1

name: javi.a.alm.local
address: 10.0.0.20
```

but when i result in debian:

```
nslookup javi.a

Server: 10.0.0.3
Address: 10.0.0.3 # 53

** server can't find javi.a: NXDOMAIN
```

why does it not solve ??

```
resolv.conf:

nameserver 10.0.0.3
search alm.local
```

Comment: Do you have set same DNS-server as the windows client in /etc/resolv.conf? Because as you see your windows Client is requesting local host while your Linux is requesting 10.0.0.3. Try nslookuo javi.a 10.0.0.3 on your windows client.

Comment: yes, I have edited the question with the settings

Comment: Is the Debian PC domain-joined?

Comment: Yes it is joined but I have also tried it without joining and nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the Linux resolver will not apply the `search` domain to a queried name that already contains a dot. So `javi.a` will be treated as a FQDN and will not have the domain `alm.local` appended to it.

You can change this behavior using the `ndots` `option`. This says the minimum number of dots that can be in a name to be treated as a FQDN. It defaults to `1`.

You should also consider the warnings in the man page `resolv.conf(5)` before doing so.

> Resolver queries having fewer than *ndots*  dots  (default
> is  1)  in  them  will  be attempted using each component of the
> search path in turn until a match is  found.   For  environments
> with  multiple  subdomains  please read **options ndots:***n* below to
> avoid man-in-the-middle attacks and unnecessary traffic for  the
> root-dns-servers.   Note  that this process may be slow and will
> generate a lot of network traffic if the servers for the  listed
> domains  are  not  local,  and  that queries will time out if no
> server is available for one of the domains.

And the documentation for `options ndots`:

> Sets a threshold for the number of dots which must appear
> in a name given to **res_query**(3) (see **resolver**(3))  before
> an  initial absolute query will be made.  The default for
> n is 1, meaning that if there are any dots in a name, the
> name  will  be tried first as an absolute name before any
> search list elements are appended to it.  The  value  for
> this option is silently capped to 15.

(Note that this implies that the name will be tried with search domains after being tried as a FQDN, but in practice this does not actually happen. It is not tried with the search domains at all. Which is why you have posted here today.)

So in resolv.conf you can add:

```
options ndots:2
```

And a name with one dot will now have the search domain appended, but names with two or more dots will not. As the man page says, you can set this as high as 15 if necessary.